# The expanded size of the tensor (1536) must match the existing size (512) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, tensor, bert-language-model

I'm trying to train my BERT model for sentences binary classification task (Inputs are 2 sentences and output label: 1 not similar and 0 for not similar). The problem arises when I trained my model, it said `RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (1536) must match the existing size (512) at non-singleton dimension 1. Target sizes: [50, 1536]. Tensor sizes: [1, 512]`. I wonder is there anyway to resize my tensor or anyway to fix this?
Here is my code:

#### Data Prepared:

```
X = np.hstack((bert_embeddings1, bert_embeddings2))
y = labels

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

#### Build model

```
model_name = "bert-base-uncased"
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, num_labels=2)

optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)

X_train = torch.tensor(X_train, dtype=torch.long)
X_test = torch.tensor(X_test, dtype=torch.long)
y_train = torch.tensor(y_train, dtype=torch.long)
y_test = torch.tensor(y_test, dtype=torch.long)
```

#### Train model

```
model.train()
for epoch in range(1):
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  outputs = model(input_ids=X_train, labels=y_train) # the code stops here
  loss = outputs.loss
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()
```

#### Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-ab00829ee5cc> in <cell line: 2>()
      2 for epoch in range(1):
      3   optimizer.zero_grad()
----> 4   outputs = model(input_ids=X_train, labels=y_train)
      5   loss = outputs.loss
      6   loss.backward()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    986             if hasattr(self.embeddings, "token_type_ids"):
    987                 buffered_token_type_ids = self.embeddings.token_type_ids[:, :seq_length]
--> 988                 buffered_token_type_ids_expanded = buffered_token_type_ids.expand(batch_size, seq_length)
    989                 token_type_ids = buffered_token_type_ids_expanded
    990             else:

RuntimeError: The expanded size of the tensor (1536) must match the existing size (512) at non-singleton dimension 1.  Target sizes: [50, 1536].  Tensor sizes: [1, 512]
```